# Show that $\gcd(3n,3n+ 2) = 1$ when $n$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

I would like to know why $\gcd(3n,3n+ 2) = 1$ when *$n$ is odd*.

I tried to use the Euclidean Algorithm, but I got confused:
$$
3n+2 = 3n + 2$$
$$3n = \ ?
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Since $n$ is odd, $n = 2k + 1$. Then what is $3n$?

Comment: $gcd(3n,3n+2)=gcd(3n,2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know that $a$ and $b$ are relative prime iff there exist integers $x$ and $y$ s.t. $ax+by=1$? See burton page $23$ , if you don't.

By that if $n$ is odd, let $n=2k+1$, then $3n=6k+3$ and $3n+2=6k+5$. Now notice that $(3k+2)(6k+3)+(-(3k+1))(6k+5)=1$.    $\hspace{8cm}$Q.E.D

Comment: Your $a = 2$ and $b = -1$ don't quite work. Consider $a = 3k + 2$ and $b = -(3k + 1)$ instead.

Comment: ohh ya silly me

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** We have (by one step of the Euclidean Algorithm)
$$\gcd(3n+2,3n)=\gcd(3n,2).$$

More informally, any common divisor of $3n+2$ and $3n$ is also a divisor of $2$.